# Python pandas read multiple csv file and turn into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I tried to read multiple .csv files that have the same format from different folders. It turns out to be a list using .append and I tried to turn it into dataframe using .concat. But it didn't let me to do so. I also tried .os to read the data. It wouldn't work. Any suggestions?

```
test = []
train = []
for f in testdata:
    test.append(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows = 5, sep = ',', names = 
         ['time','avg_rss12','var_rss12','avg_rss13','var_rss13','avg_rss23','var_rss23']))
for f in traindata:
    train.append(pd.read_csv(f, skiprows = 5, sep = ',', names = 
         ['time','avg_rss12','var_rss12','avg_rss13','var_rss13','avg_rss23','var_rss23']))
```

[image: here is one .csv file data]

Comment: What didn't work with `pd.concat()`? Could you please show what you tried, this is the correct approach to the problem if all of your frames are of the same schema. Did you specify which axis to perform the concatenation along? I think rows is the default axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention attempting pandas `concat`, but don't specify how it failed. It is the way you would want to go. Using just your test loop from the question:

```
import pandas as pd


frames = []
for f in testdata:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skiprows=5, sep=',', names=['time','avg_rss12','var_rss12','avg_rss13','var_rss13','avg_rss23','var_rss23'])
    frames.append(df)
combined = pd.concat(frames)
```

What gets passed into `concat()` needs to be a list of DataFrame instances, which it will combine into a single frame.